# Create a custom permsetup.aspx and add extra text fields for new groups

Tags: development, javascript, csom, newform

I have the following requirement:

When a user creates a new site via Site Settings\Site Content\New Subsite, and he selects "use unique permissions", the user is redirected to the page: permsetup.aspx where he can enter different SharePoint groups.

My question is: how can I enter other text fields in the page permsetup.aspx which allows the user to create extra groups?